# Access columns after pandas merge gave them suffixes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, suffix

I have two dataframes:

```
d1 = {'id': [1, 1, 2], 'date': [pd.Timestamp('2020-10-16'), pd.Timestamp('2020-10-18'), pd.Timestamp('2020-12-4')], 'var1': [1, 2, 2]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

d2 = {'id': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'date': [pd.Timestamp('2020-10-11'), pd.Timestamp('2020-10-18'), pd.Timestamp('2020-12-3'), pd.Timestamp('2020-12-13')], 'var2': [1, 2, 2, 5]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

After performing an outer merge on id, the resulting df looks like this:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2,on='id', how='outer', suffixes=['_x','_y']).fillna(pd.NA)
>> df_merged
df_merged
   id      date_x  var1      date_y  var2
0   1  2020-10-16     1  2020-10-11     1
1   1  2020-10-16     1  2020-10-18     2
2   1  2020-10-18     2  2020-10-11     1
3   1  2020-10-18     2  2020-10-18     2
4   2  2020-12-04     2   2020-12-3     2
5   2  2020-12-04     2  2020-12-13     5
```

I want to perform operations on the two date columns. However, I am unsure on how to access them since their name changed due to the merge (i.e., pandas added the _x and _y suffixes).
Of course I could manually add the _x and _y suffixes to the end of my column names before performing the operations, but this does not cover the cases where the two date column names have names which differ from each other (e.g. 'date1' and 'date2'), therefore the _x and _y  suffixes wouldn't have been added.
The operation I want to perform looks like this:

```
df_merged['time_difference'] = abs((df_merged[date1_column_name] - df_merged[date2_column_name]).dt.days)
```

How can I cover both the case that pandas added the suffixes and that no suffixes were added, therefore the date columns kept their original names?

Comment: So, sometimes you have dates that are the same and sometimes you have dates that are different?  Always append something to the date column to make the date header different before the merge.

Comment: Yes. Sometimes I have two date columns with the same name (like in this example, 'date' and 'date'). Sometimes the date columns will have different names (for example, 'date1' in df1 and 'date2' in df2). 
Do you suggest I should just manually add suffixes before the actual merge and that way control for both cases?